# How to know which partition will be used in Postgres hash partitioning?

Tags: postgresql, hash, partition

Is there a way to know which partition will be used for a new row in a table partitioned by a column with text values?

Use case is:
I have a big table with many partitions according to a text column. I need to insert-update millions of new rows to this table. If I know which partitions will be used for each row, I can rearrange my bulk inserts-updates to only work on 1 partition at a time.

-> hashtext function is tested and it is not giving the correct partition value.

Comment: The only reason for hash partitioning is to distribute I/O, so I don't see why you want to avoid that.

Comment: The linked post doesn't really answer the question.  'b' goes to partition with modulus 8 remainder 6, but how does `hashtext('b')=-68,821,088` explain that?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe  Surely you might want to distribute IO sometimes (like normal operations), but not others (like bulk loading, where keeping the partition indexes cached in RAM can be very important).  If all you wanted to do is distribute IO unconditionally and uncontrollably, why partition at all?  Just use RAID/JBOD.

Comment: @jjanes True; `hashtext` is not the answer. Can there be a good reason for hash partitioning except spreading I/O?

Comment: Thank you @jjanes. Whoever made this question get closed deserves a punishment and you deserve thanks. People are so eager to tag questions and close them as if I didnt see that related question. Quite strange behaviors.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe if I try to insert(many times upsert) to all partitions at the same time, all partitions suffer from locks because I read from that table a lot during the time. Plus, autovacuum is hard on unpartitioned version. However, I thought If I can run parallel inserts only on some of the partitions, I can make insertion process faster and reads from the table doesnt suffer that much. Is it a feasible solution?

Comment: The locks taken by `INSERT` and `SELECT` don't conflict, so I see no problem here.

Comment: 4b rows are available and daily 150m rows get updated, 30m rows get inserted. Updates are problematic. When it is partitioned, I can run parallel updates-inserts to partitions separately as much as my cpu cores allow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reverse engineering the code, you can get the partition number with the following statement:

```
SELECT (hashtextextended('value', 8816678312871386365)::numeric + 5305509591434766563) % 8;
```

Replace 8 with the number of partitions and `'value'` with the string in question.

You can test the partition number with `satisfies_hash_partition`. To test if `'value'` would end up in partition 6 of 8 in table `tab`, you can run

```
SELECT satisfies_hash_partition('tab'::regclass, 8, 6, 'value'::text);
```

Comment: Wow, reverse engineered part is amazing and both solutions work. Thank you.

Comment: first query statement will return negative value, the result doesn't look right with negative remainder.
`SELECT (hashtextextended('03772ebe9f914e6dadaa0eebfaae5afb', 8816678312871386365)::numeric + 5305509591434766563) % 127;`
take this as example, remainder is -70, but it will be inserted into partition 59

Comment: @LHJ Right, I forgot the integer overflow.